# Can I change my display name programmatically?

Tags: support, status-declined, display-names, profile-picture

I saw this user: [dxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/291201/dxiv) and I thought that their name was their score in Roman Numerals, (or was at some time). Alas, they have way more than 514 points.

But I wondered if there is a way to make my display name show my number of reputation points? That way it would be easily visible in comments. (A long time ago I tried to get my Unix Shell Prompt to run a shell script to change the prompt string every time it appears, but I was not able to do that.)

Wait.. how often can we change our profile picture?

Comment: well that took about 1 minute. Maybe the my display name should be the total number of downvotes I have received instead.

Comment: Cute idea, but... pretty much every place your name shows up already shows your reputation as well. And given we don't allow changing the display name very often (to avoid much confusion for others and abuse of the feature), so... not really workable.

Comment: But the real issue with the feature request - what's the benefit here for the site and most users?

Comment: I used to drive past that big sign on I-94 which showed the total number of cars produced by Ford so far that year.

Comment: Benefit schmenefit, I am here to have fun buddy!

Comment: I guess you haven't seen [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), then ;)

Comment: You can change your profile pic as often as you want.

Comment: @nicael YES! Now I can learn something new that will help me in my job! And have fun too!

Answer (score 2):

You can already do this. Just send the appropriate HTTP POST to `/users/edit/{your-user-id}/post`, with all your SE cookies and so forth. It's not all that complicated.
(You can only do this once every 30 days, so if you use the site often it'll lag behind your actual rep.)

Here's a dump of a POST body that could change your name:

```
ProfileImageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2Fh4JIA.png%3Fs%3D128%26g%3D1&ProfileImageType=63&DisplayName=Functino&Location=&WoeId=&AboutMe=&WebsiteUrl=&TwitterUrl=&GitHubUrl=&RealName=[my real name]&Email=[my email]&Birthday=&push=true&fields=&author=&fkey=[gibberish]&i1l=[gibberish]
```

Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

The relevant field would be DisplayName.

I have to say, though, that it's a terrible idea. Most notably, you'd be breaking @mentions in comments if your display name changed every 30 days.

Bottom line, your display name should be a way for people to identify you. If you break that for the benefit of a silly script, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: ... and you can basically only run this once every 30-days as that is how often you are allowed to change your displayname per site ...

Comment: Apparently, you like to keep an air of mystery about you... I don't think that identifiability makes much difference for the vast majority of users, and their profile names are often incomprehensible or silly anyhow. I guess if I can only change the name every 30 days, I could just use the name of the month. Then everyone would know it was me. I suppose your Post suggestion would work for changing my profile picture. I could just choose a random new pic every day or something. Then people would know it was me - "Oh, the guy who always changes his picture!"